# How to loop conditionally to map header rows to data rows

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, loops, datatables

If I have two types of rows:

`header rows` and `data rows`. and any row should compose of `18 columns`.

The number of data rows is based on the number of header rows for example:

```
If I have 2 header rows, I should have (2 datarows: the first one map to the first header row, the second one map to the second header row + 2 datarows: the first one map to the first header row, the second one map to the second header row + 1 data rows for total: maps to the first header row ) = 5 datarows per group

If I have 3 header rows, I should have (3 datarows: the first one map to the first header row, the second one map to the second header row, the third one maps to the third header row + 3 datarows: the first one maps to the first header row, the second one maps to the second header row, the third one mapss to the third header row + 1 for total: maps to the first header row) = 7 datarowsper group
```

and so on

```
NOTE: ALWAYS I SHOULD HAVE ONE DATA ROW FOR THE TOTAL DATA ROWS.
```

I want to loop over the columns of the data rows and map to the related header col data:

```
"render": function (data, type, full, meta) {

           let tooltip = isNaN(data) ? data : Number(data);

           return type === 'display' ? '<div  id="tooltip" data-tooltip="' +parsedData.columns[meta.col].toString().split("-")[0] + " = " + tooltip + "|" + meta.row + '">' + data : data;
    }
```

---

Let's take The second example: I have two header rows:

```
parsedData.columns = array[36] where 36 = 2 * 18 = number of header rows * number of columns per row.

There are multiple data rows one array for each data row = one row array[18]

meta.row = row index
```

The problem in my code is that it always maps to the first header row whatever the number of header rows.

To solve this problem I want to do a conditional loop.

so If `the number of header rows = array[36] /18 = 2` header rows:

> - The first data row Iteration :    `parsedData.columns[meta.col].toString().split("-")[0]`
> - the second data row iteration : `parsedData.columns[meta.col-18].toString().split("-")[0]`
> - The third data row Iteration :    `parsedData.columns[meta.col].toString().split("-")[0]`
> - The fourth data row iteration : `parsedData.columns[meta.col-18].toString().split("-")[0]`
> - The fifth data row iteration:(for total) so the first `parsedData.columns[meta.col].toString().split("-")[0]`

```
and repeat this pattern for each group of row data(5 data rows per group), may I have 3 groups so I have 15 data rows
```

---

Based on comments here's an example:

[image]

```
528.00  -->Tooltip should = A1:528.00
52.80   -->Tooltip should = B9:52.80
240.00- -->Tooltip should = B10:240.00-
91.52   -->Tooltip should = T5:91.52
```

---

- The header rows in this example = an array[36]
- The data rows are multiple arrays(5) each array = array[18]

because I have 2 header rows ---> I have 5 data rows

```
2 + 2 + 1(total).
```

Now I Want to map every tool tip cell in the data rows to its equivalent of header rows as illustrated above. but it always maps to the first header row.

Comment: Could you add an example input dataset and an expected result?

Comment: Do you have the guarantee that your input dataset always comes in the right order? e.g. `[HR][DR][HR][DR][HR][DR]...[TR]`? If so, you can treat each row by its index and assess if it's odd or even. The total row will always come last and it's index equals total-1.

Comment: @Gigabyte the header rows don’t repeat with data row. If i have 2hd then i have 6dr or 12dr or 18dr or  24dr according to the grouping, I jest want to do mapping correctly

Comment: Want the answer in JS or C#?

Comment: I want the answer in js, but i tag c# because I understand it more than js, so if some one who can solve the problem but just in c# i will try to convert it to its equivalent in JavaScript, but I prefer the answer in js.@ArmanEbrahimpour

Comment: Can you provide two illustrated examples of the incoming source data and the end-state that you're trying to achieve @AnynameDonotcare? The question seems to explain an algorithmic approach now.

Comment: @DanieleRicci I have ediited my question and put an example

Comment: Is it correct if I say `parsedData` is an array of strings with length = `2 * n` ? Why every 6 elements the `|` character is double? Can it happen the double `|` character is every 2, 3 or 9 (other integer divisors of 18) element? I see you use `.split("|")` in your question: what to do about the *empty* element between the two consecutive `|` characters? What is `meta` ? Can you see how many question I have? Could you please provide what `console.log(all input data)` dumps for some significant example cases and your not working code so we can argue what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @DanieleRicci I'm so sorry for this confusion, the `|` is some thing logical it's like a border between cells in HTML Table, I double it after six cols for business concept, but it has no effect at all at my question. and for splitting with '|' in my code ignore it. My question all about mapping the cell of the data row to its equivalent in the header row.

Comment: I'm sorry too, but without input data and expected result is really hard to help you; so, please once forever, provide us your input data, your expected result and your not working code, so we can stop this useless ping pong and start providing answers to your problem.

Comment: @DanieleRicci the info is significantly secure and can’t show them but I will try to do console log mimic data

Comment: In your example: `If I have 3 header rows, ... = 8 datarowsper group` - what is the reason that header row 3 does *not* have a totals row?

Comment: @ShaiCohen :Excuse me I edit my question and add a photo to illustrate the idea, and total should always  =1 row not two.

Comment: So there is only 1 total row? Did you mean 3 "subtotal" (my term) rows and 1 "grand total" (my term) row? Which would be _**10**_ total rows

Comment: @ShaiCohen the row for total is the white row, i have two green + two red + 1 white for total = 5 data rows per group if i have two header rows as in the example. If i have 4 groups then i have 4*5 = 20 data row

Comment: How are you providing data to the datatable? Do you render the html table first and then invoke `datatable`? Or do you provide the `data` option with a json object? Or do you use the `ajax` option of datatable?

Comment: @NiK648  I use  `$.ajax()` with a web service to prepare the `json object(columns,data)`, then 
`table = $('#displayTable').DataTable({data: parsedData.data, ....`

Comment: I'm not sure i understand you well, but if the columns count is constant (18), then to calculate header addres, you need to pass `meta.Column` to function: `public int[] GeHeaderAddress(int metaCol)
{
 int noOfColumns = 18;
 int currCol = (int)(metaCol%noOfColumns);
 int currRow = (int)(metaCol/noOfColumns);
 int[] address = new int[]{currRow,currCol};
 return address;
}` For `meta.Column` = `18`, it would be `{1,0}`. A'm i right?

Comment: 6 days, dozens of comment and we continue to say "I'm not sure I have understood your question". I hope at least you understood the value of a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), @AnynameDonotcare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find correspondence header we need to consider total header rows in our calculation.

Then the below javascript function will return the header location (meta.col)

```js
function getHeaderCol(totalHeaderRows, dataRow, dataCol){
    const groupRows = (2 * totalHeaderRows) + 1
    const newDataRow = dataRow % groupRows
     return ((newDataRow % totalHeaderRows) * 18) + dataCol
    }
    
    console.log(getHeaderCol(2,4,10)) // result 10 , group 1
    console.log(getHeaderCol(2,5,10)) // result 10 , group 2
```

Comment: If I have multiple group say two groups = 10 data rows, It fails, the row 6 should belong to header 1 but it belongs to header 2

Comment: I updated the function to work with multiple groups, if I got it correctly. dataRow and dataCol start from zero.  Have a look and give your feedback please. @AnynameDonotcare

Answer (score 1):

**Initial note:**

I'm not JavaScript specialist, but you've mentioned that you'll be glad even for C# solution...

As to your requirements...

> ...
>
> header rows and data rows. and any row should compose of 18 columns
>
> ...
>
> I Want to map every tool tip cell in the data rows to its equivalent
> of header rows as illustrated above. but it always maps to the first
> header row.

Assuming that the number of columns in a destination table is constant (18), an algorithm to find corresponing header addres is just clear mathematics:

```
public int[] GeHeaderAddress(int metaCol)
{
    int noOfColumns = 18;
    int currCol = (int)(metaCol%noOfColumns);
    int currRow = (int)(metaCol/noOfColumns);
    int[] address = new int[]{currRow,currCol};
    return address;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
int[] address = GeHeaderAddress(18);
//returns {1,0} //as the arrays are zero-based indexed
```

Comment: Thanks but still the same problem. Could U take care that `the header is a single array= array[18*2] =array[36]`. `the data row = multiple arrays each one = array[18]`

Comment: Sorry, but i don't get you... As you can see, in `Usage` section i used `18`, which means that function have to get the number of header row  by using original column index (of input array[36]). Please, clarify your input data.

Comment: Ex: B10 which in the second row of the header = row index ‘21’

Comment: Based on the picture you provided: `row index = 21` does not refer to `B10`! Counting from left to right 21. "cell" refers to header under the `T4`. That's why i was asking you for sample input data. I'm guessing that it's something like this: `string[] stringData = new string[] { "A1-A2-A3-A4-A5-A6-A7-A8-A9-A10-A11-A12-B1-B2-B3-B4-B5-B6-B7-B8-B9-B10-B11-B12-T1-T2-T3-T4-T5-T6-T7-T8-T9-T10-T11-T12", "-91.52--1160-6163-188--10.56--17.6--5.28----632--528-----8-0.36----52.8--5.28------"};` So, when you "convert" this into array with constant number of columns, you need to pass only column no.